# Use offchain date time

Tags: solidity, security, timestamp

in my contract, I need to do something based on time, and this is quite sensitive, and as we know, you cannot rely on the `block.timestamp` because it can be changed, I want to know if there is a way that I can use the time stamp correctly or use it from somewhere?

Comment: `block.timestamp` is accurate to 12 seconds. no more no less, it is exactly in 12 seconds intervals.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can use Oracles to determine accurate time and off chain data in general

Comment: I want to use in my own Blockchain and there is not any oracle on this chain